# Can I separate image on arbitrary colors?

Tags: image-processing, colors, imagemagick

Is it possible to separate an image into channels based on arbitrary colors? If I have an image that's visually pink, white and black, is it possible to create 3 separate images describing the "pinkyness" "whiteness" and "blackness" channels?

My purpose is to mutate - let's say - pink into yellow, black into blue and white into red.

Ideally this should be possible with ImageMagick

I would use color substitution but it would substitutes all colors close to pink with one single colors, whereas I want to preserve the different levels of intensity of pink.

Using [this](https://stockx.imgix.net/Adidas-NMD-R1-Primeknit-Pink-Rose-W.png) image as an example, I'd like to turn the knit part rom pink/white/black into blue/yellow/green.

Comment: It can be done but **ImageMagick** doesn’t really lend itself to things that need visual feedback and eyeballing on a case-by-case basis such as setting thresholds for affected hues. I would go for **Photoshop**’s `Replace Colour` tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the hue channel from HCL or HSL, etc and mask and swap hues. I have a bash Unix shell script, replace color, for Imagemagick that will do that.

Input:

[image]

```
replacecolor -i "#BA3A67" -o blue Adidas-pink.png Adidas-blue.png
```

`#BA3A67` is your input pinkish color that I measured. `Blue` is the desired output color. Any opaque color can be use and specified as a color name or hex value or rgb(rr,gg,bb) triplet.

[image]

The script cannot change gray tones (black, gray, white), since the hue is the same as red. But you can still change black and/or white (or any color) in imagemagick using:

```
convert image.suffix -fuzz XX% -fill newcolor -opaque oldcolor output.suffix
```

Where XX is some percent tolerance.

See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/replacecolor/index.php

Comment: Thanks @fmw42 that is very likely to work perfectly as I actually could have control on the colors of the initial image. BTW - I'm great fan of your scripts - thanks a lot for all the work.